# Convolution of three indicator functions

Tags: analysis, convolution

I have 2 functions $f(x)=1_{[-1,1]}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{2\epsilon}1_{[-\epsilon,\epsilon]}$

My questions is how to calculate the convolution $f\ast g\ast g$.
I know that $g \ast g$ is the piecewise function:

$\frac{2\epsilon+x}{4\epsilon^2}$ for $-2\epsilon \leq x < 0$

$\frac{1}{2\epsilon}$ for $x=0$

$\frac{2\epsilon-x}{4\epsilon^2}$ for $0 < x \geq 2\epsilon$

But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: Draw pictures. You might also want to google "convolution of a box function with a triangle function", but really, just draw the pictures and give it a good try.

Answer (score 1):

Let $2\epsilon\le1$, we have that
\begin{align}
(f\ast g\ast g)(x)&=\int_{\Bbb R}f(t)(g\ast g)(x-t)dt\\
&=\int_{\Bbb R}\chi_{[-1,1]}(g\ast g)(x-t)dt\\
&=\int_{-1}^1(g\ast g)(x-t)dt\\
&=\int_{-1}^1(g\ast g)(x-t)\chi_{[x-2\epsilon,x+2\epsilon]}dt\\
&=\int_{\max(x-2\epsilon,-1)}^{\min(x+2\epsilon,1)}(g\ast g)(x-t)dt\\
&=\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
\frac{(x+1+2\epsilon)^2}{8\epsilon^2}&,\text{ if }-2\epsilon-1\le x\le-1\\
1-\frac{(x+1-2\epsilon)^2}{8\epsilon^2}&,\text{ if }-1\le x\le-1+2\epsilon\\
1&,\text{ if }-1+2\epsilon\le x\le1-2\epsilon\\
1-\frac{(x-1+2\epsilon)^2}{8\epsilon^2}&,\text{ if }1-2\epsilon\le x\le1\\
\frac{(x-1-2\epsilon)^2}{8\epsilon^2}&,\text{ if }1\le x\le1+2\epsilon\\
\end{aligned} 
\right.\\
\end{align}
which gives
[image]

I leave the case $2\epsilon>1$ for you.

Comment: I don't understand your solution. $g \ast g (x-t)$ gives the piecewise function I stated in my question but with $x=x-t$. If I integrate this function for t I get a totally different result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know your problem but if $x-t$ bother you you can use the substitution $u=x-t$.

Comment: $\int(g \ast g)(x-t) dt$ is $\frac{4\epsilon t -t^2+2tx}{8\epsilon^2}$ for $-2\epsilon+z\leq x <t$, $\frac{1}{2\epsilon}$ for $x=t$ and $\frac{4\epsilon t +t^2-2tx}{8\epsilon^2}$ for $t<x \leq 2\epsilon+t$

Comment: You'd better calculate directly the area.

Comment: I'm sorry for being so obtuse, but what do you mean by calculating the area directly?

Comment: The integral is the area of the region bounded by the graph of the function. For $g\ast g$ it will be a triangle, right?